# MySQL Statement that combines tables into single table

Tags: mysql

So I'm not all to great at complex MySQL statements so I'm hoping you guys can help me out.

Say I have four tables, MainTable, AttrTable, NameTable, and ValueTable.

MainTable looks like this:

```
| id | title | category |
.........................
| 1  | First | Cat1     |
.........................
| 2  | Second| Cat2     |
.........................
| 3  | Third | Cat3     |
```

AttrTable looks like this:

```
| id | mainId | nameId | valueId |
..................................
| 1  | 1      | 1      | 2       |
..................................
| 2  | 1      | 2      | 1       |
..................................
| 3  | 2      | 1      | 3       |
..................................
| 4  | 3      | 3      | 2       |
..................................
| 1  | 3      | 1      | 1       |
```

NameTable and ValueTable each looks like this:

```
| id | title |           | id | title |
..............           ..............
| 1  | foo   |           | 1  | bar   |
..............           ..............
| 2  | john  |           | 2  | smith |
..............           ..............
| 3  | dink  |           | 3  | fink  |
```

So I want to write a statement that combines all the data associated with each row of the MainTable into its own row. Eg: I want a statment that would give me back something like:

```
| 1 | First | Cat1 | foo | smith | john | bar |
| 2 | Second| Cat2 | foo | fink  |
etc...
```

Is that possible? I'd even settle for something like:

```
| 1 | First  | Cat1 | foo  | smith |
| 1 | First  | Cat1 | john | bar   |
| 2 | Second | Cat2 | foo  | fink  |
etc...
```

Hopefully this all makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just want this:

```
select m.id,
    m.title,
    m.category,
    n.title,
    v.title
from maintable m
left join attrtable a
    on m.id = a.mainid
left join nametable n
    on a.nameid = n.id
left join valuetable v
    on a.valueid = v.id
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b893/1)

Comment: That works great! But I forgot to mention in my question that I also want to display rows from MainTable that don't have any rows in AttrTable. i.e. I want to still see row 3 from MainTable even if it doesn't feature in AttrTable.

Comment: @gordon you can change the first join to a `left join` instead of `inner join`. Then if the `attr` table is null you will get records.

Answer (score 0):

Query not checked!  (and may need to be tweaked)

select m.*, n.title, v.title from MainTable m
join AttrTable a on a.mainId = m.id
join NameTable n on n.id = a.nameId
join ValueTable v on v.id = a.valueId